# Statistics on IT incidents in Unix and/or Linux environments

Tags: linux, administration

I am interesting in what are the possible most common incidents admins face in day to day Unix/Linux environments (i.e. service down, file system full, cpu spike, memory full) administration. Are there research pointing out what are they? Are there any public available dataset listing incidents a big size organization faced during a given period?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think any statistic such as this would be reliable. Problems are often the cause of how people design and develop services. One typical problem might be log file rotation and general house keeping. Off the back of this perhaps the type of problem where the log file is not closed properly and the disk fills up due to an application writing to a removed file, yet the open FD continues to consume.

This is entirely dependant on how the individual application owner authors the program.

You would be better off looking at what applications are in use in an organisation and take a look at the user mail lists to see what the common problems are. You could take this a step further by looking at the default applications that are part of the distribution that you're interested in.